# Expand the provided code to cover the whole table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to compare two dynamic tables of the same size, and need to expand the provided code to cover the whole table.  Every time I try an edit, I get the error that the data and range are of two different sizes

I am still fairly new to scripting, and my knowledge of arrays is sketchy at best.  I am sure the issue is something to do with that.

```
function compareTEST() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('FIRST');
  var values1 = sheet1.getRange('b3:e8').getValues()[0];            
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1csTKgthrUpZoYMf-d-8y54h9N-tecsNZftLoaOF8u-s');
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName('SECOND');
  var values2 = sheet2.getRange('b3:e8').getValues()[0];            
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var backgrounds = []; 
  Logger.log(values1)
  Logger.log(values2)
  Logger.log(backgrounds)
  for (var k = 1; k < values1.length; k++) {
backgrounds.push(values2[k] == values1[k] ? 'light orange 1' : 'cyan');
  }
  sheet1.getRange('b3:e8').setBackgrounds([backgrounds]);
}
```

I have gotten the function to execute for only one row, but my table has 4 columns and 6 rows

Comment: Perhaps you can share your spreadsheet with the two tables that you wanted to compare and explain what your desire output should be.

Comment: I am unable to share as they are administered by my company.  This is a proof of concept model.  Right now the two tables are just a list of names, But on the second table, some of the names are changed.  I want to highlight those that are different on the second table.

Comment: values1 and values2 are just the first row.  And iterating from k=1 to k<values1.length leaves out the first column.  So the width of backgrounds is value1.length -1 (3) and the height is 1 where your range is  4 x 6 so it will never work without starting over and figuring out what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: Then share an example that you make up so that we can have a [mcve].

Comment: Both tables are in range b3:e8 on their respective sheets.  But eventually this will need to be dynamic as the tables will be fed by a google form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function compareTEST1(r) {
  var r=r||'b3:e8';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('FIRST');
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(r);
  var ss2=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1csTKgthrUpZoYMf-d-8y54h9N-tecsNZftLoaOF8u-s');
  var sh2=ss2.getSheetByName('SECOND');
  var rg2=sh2.getRange(r);
  var values1=rg1.getValues();            
  var values2=rg2.getValues();            
  var bgs=rg1.getBackgrounds(); //using background array for the loop now
  for(var i=0;i<bgs.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<bgs[i].length;j++) {
      if(values1[i][j]!=values2[i][j]) {
        bgs[i][j]='#ffff00';
      }
    }
  }
  rg1.setBackgrounds(bgs);//changes the backgrounds of both sheets
  rg2.setBackgrounds(bgs);
}
```

Comment: This is working!!!!  From here I should be able to expand it to cover all of my needs.  Thank you so much, Cooper!!

Comment: Note I made another change so that the background is only written to when there is a difference between the two values.  That way your normal background remains unchanged.